# Assigning one variable to another based on (and within) macro

Tags: r

I am using `RStudio 0.98.1062`.
What I am trying to do is within a macro to create a new variable based on another one (that already has a suffix defined by me) in the same dataframe . The name of the data frame, and the index(suffix) are macro variables.
Here is my code:

```
read_data <- defmacro(fileName, monthIndex, dfName,
                          expr = {
  dfName <- read.table(fileName, head=TRUE,sep = ",")
  #add suffix vor the variables for the corresponding month
  colnames(dfName) <- paste(colnames(dfName),monthIndex, sep = "_")
  #dfName["EasyClientMerge"]<-numeric()

  within(dfName, assign("EasyClientMerge",   paste("dfName$EasyClientNumber",monthIndex,sep="_"))

})
```

if the macro parameters are `(..., monthIndex=6, dfName= m201309)` I expect the following variable to be created
`m201309$EasyClientMerge<-m201309$EasyClient_6`

first of all a new variable is not created within the data frame and second of all it seems that a string is taken `"m201309$EasyClient_6`" rather than reference to dataframe & variable name

Thanks a lot in advance cause I am kind of stuck!

Comment: First, you're using R through IDE called Rstudio. R has functions, not macros. Unless I'm wrong, the syntax for the function is wrong. There is a better way to go about this. You should not hard-code data.frame names. I suggest you use lists. What are you trying to achieve in the long run?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik why you think this is wrong idea? I really depend on what is the purpose of this code. However, can you clarify why list is better approache?

Comment: I may be not doing the smartest way but this is how I am used to from SAS. What I am doing is as follows : 1) Importing mutiple templated data files 2) putting indexes for all the variables so that in each data frame all variables are unique compared to the rest of the files 3) creating a variable that is the same across all data frames so that I can easily use it for merging 4) Merge all data frames together based on the key variable

Comment: Due to many functions that utilize lists, this approach is more natural, flexible and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on producing hard coded data.frames within a function (in my opinion a bad choice), you can do it like so.

```
> dfName <- "new.df"
> assign(dfName, value = list(clientMerge = 1:10, clientMerge2 = 1:10))
> as.data.frame(new.df)
   clientMerge clientMerge2
1            1            1
2            2            2
3            3            3
4            4            4
5            5            5
6            6            6
7            7            7
8            8            8
9            9            9
10          10           10
```